# How can I play as more players in a custom game?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-5

In Heroes V: Tribes of the East, I can only control one player in a custom game. Back in the day, I remember that it wasn't like that. I could play as the red and blue player for example, while the AI controls green and yellow player.
Any ides how can I play as more players?

Comment: in heroes 3 there was a "hot-seat" option, so you can play with multiple players at one pc, dont know if this is implemented in heroes 5

Comment: Thank you! I don't even know how I missed it to be honest, guess I'm just blind. :D

Comment: is there such an option in heroes 5 ?

Answer (score -1):

in heroes 3 there was a "hot-seat" option, so you can play with multiple players at one pc, dont know if this is implemented in heroes 5.

So as I did some research, there is a Hot-Seat Option in the Multiplayer Mode. So you can play a local multiplayer match on one pc.